# Adding new methods to specializations of standard templates (std::vector, std::list...)

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I would like to create specialization for `std::list<Picture>` which would add additional method for this list containing `Picture`, but I don't know if is it possible in this way which I tried.

I tried:

```
template <typename _Alloc = std::allocator<Picture>> 
   class list : protected _List_base<Picture, _Alloc>
{
public:
  void draw()
  {
    // some code
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::list<Picture> myList;
  //adding elements to mylist
  mylist.draw();
  return 0;
}
```

After compilation I have an error:

> `error: ‘class std::__cxx11::list<Picture>’ has no member named ‘draw’`

Comment: Please don't. Add non-member functions `void draw(std::list<Picture> const& )` and `void draw(std::vector<Picture> const& )`.

Comment: @Frank there is nothing which is 'not allowed' here.

Comment: `_List_base` is an implementation detail of whatever standard library you're using. (It has an ugly name on purpose.) You're not supposed to touch it. It might not be there if you switch to a different compiler with a different standard library implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Specializing STL types

You are allowed to specialize STL types, but as mentioned in the other answer, they need to be specialized in namespace std. This means you should either do this:

```
namespace std {
    template <typename _Alloc = std::allocator<Picture>> 
    class list<Picture, _Alloc> { 
        /* stuff */ 
    };
}
```

Or this:

```
template<typename _Alloc = std::allocator<Picture>>
class std::list<Picture, _Alloc> {
    /* stuff
};
```

That being said, **Don't inherit from `_List_base`**. That class is an implementation detail of `std::list`, which means that it's a way one particular implementation of the standard library chose to implement `std::list`. Other compilers may not have it.

### Solving your problem

If you want to have a list-like class that has a `.draw()` function, you can instead inherit from `std::list`:

```
template<class Drawable>
class DrawableList : public std::list<Drawable>
{
   public: 
    // It's handy to have this to refer to the base
    using base_t = std::list<Drawable>; 
    
    using base_t::base_t; // Use std::list`s constructor
    
    // Add your draw function
    void draw(int x, int y) {
        for(Drawable& item : *this) {
            item.draw(x, y); 
        }
    }
};
```

#### Caveats of inheriting from `std::list`

There are some caveats to inheriting from `std::list`. Because `std::list` doesn't need dynamic polymorphism, that means that it doesn't have a virtual destructor (or any other virtual methods). You're basically just making a wrapper class around `std::list`.

In addition, if you add any fields to your `DrawableList`, those could get cut off when copying it to a `std::list`. This is known as object slicing.

```
DrawableList<Picture> a = /* stuff */;

std::list<Picture> b = a; // This will compile without any issues

DrawableList<Picture> c = b; // Oops; any extra fields you had in a got cut off
```

Alternatively, just use a free `draw` function:

```
void draw(std::list<Picture>& pictures, int x, int y) {
    for(auto& picture : pictures) {
        picture.draw(x, y); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a mention of object slicing

Comment: You could solve the slicing issue using `private` inheritance.  Then you don't need to worry about the lack of the virtual destructor as well.

Answer (score 1):

Specialization of STL types is explicitly allowed by standard. However, you need to specialize in the namespace `std`.

Also, inheriting from `_List_base` is something which is prohibited by C++ standard. As listed on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers, using reserved identifiers in your program makes your program ill-formed, and all identifiers starting with an underscore followed by capital letter are reserved.

Comment: Mentioning the token `_List_base` makes your program ill-formed, no diagnostic required, in every version of C++.  `_List_base` is a token that can only be used by the compiler (including `std` library implementors) under the standard.  So this isn't just "not guaranteed to work", it violates the explicit rules of well-formed programs.  And not even in a nice way.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I was not aware that mere usage of the identifier is prohibited. I will edit.

Comment: The rule is "no `__` and no leading `_` followed by a capital letter" roughly.  The std uses these identifiers **internally** exactly because other programmers are not allowed to touch them (say, `#define` them to something else); people who copy std code thus generate ill-formed programs.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I do understand the rules regarding underscores, but I always thought they apply to creating such identifiers. I didn't know that using the ones already existing in implementation and otherwise visible is also undefined.